# ESP32CAM not working when powering through battery

Tags: power-supply, esp32

I am trying to power esp32cam (ESP32-S board) from battery and it is not working. I have used it powering it through FTDI programmer and it was working fine. Now I want to use it as a product and want to power it through the battery.

The things I have tried are (Input and output voltage has been measured by multimeter)

1. Power through 3.7V Lenovo Li-Ion battery(3000mAh) (used in Lenovo mobiles).
2. Power through 8V(8000mAh) battery and buck converter converting to 5v then to ESP32CAM.
3. Power through 8V(8000mAh) battery and l8705 voltage regulator(which gives an output of 5v when input is greater than 7) with some capacitors as suggested by some websites and then the output of 5.1V to ESP32CAM.

I tried all the above and no result. I think if someone has used microcontrollers with the battery will have a good knowledge and will be able to help.

Thanks.

Comment: This is going to take more detail - you may be falling below the minimum input voltage of some of these regulators.  Keep in mind that 7.4v is a *nominal* voltage - you'll see 8.4 freshly charged and under 7 when depleted, though you should probably stop operation at that point to not overdrain the cells.  Battery powered systems are really not simple to engineer at all.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It didn't work for even a second. I have mentioned that output voltage from all the above(except Lenovo battery) was 5v I have checked it with Multimeter. Thanks

Comment: "Didn't work" isn't a very useful description.  First make sure you are using a regulator with a appropriate specs, then measure what is actually happening - what is the input voltage and the output in the actual attempt?   Beware that this project is going to be very very difficult to get to a point where it is actually useful, and even then you may only gain a very short runtime of an hour or two.  Realistically you probably need mains power.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I cant use the mains power it has to be portable any suggestions on how to power it?

Comment: For the kind of short operation duration you're likely to get from a DIY battery solution, a USB powerbank might not be a bad choice.  Imperfect as that is, it's probably going to take a fair amount of experience to build anything better, though if you are going to enter some sort of power saving mode with the ESP then the power bank's controller may become a problem as it may think you've been unplugged and never start back up again.